# Fill combobox according to month of days value

Tags: c#

I am doing a c# project of making "Age Calculator" and I have the following problem:

When i select February from month's combo box then in date's combo box it shows 1-31 numbers. But i want to show 1-29.How can i solve this without database?

Comment: You have to compute the number of days in the month, and fill the combobox with those values.  If you force the user to put in the month first, you can fill the day combo box in the month combobox SelectedValueChanged event.  The easiest way, though, is to use a datepicker.

Comment: I want to show day numbers automatically in combo box after selecting month name.

Comment: Yes, I know. Is what I said unclear?

Comment: By hooking the [SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the month combo, checking if it has February in it, and populating the [items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection of the Days combo box with the numbers 1 through 29.

Comment: Warning 1 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedValue == "February")
        {
            for (int i=1; i<=29; i++)
                Listbox2.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Warning 1 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'